# Need shell script to transform a CSV into Apache httpd format

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, csv

Need some pointing in right direction on script to fetch and regex or sed.

Site24x7 provides a URL with a CSV list of their source IP's used for monitoring. (they also provide other formats, CSV seems the least messed up as their structure leaves a lot to be desired. https://www.site24x7.com/multi-location-web-site-monitoring.html )

Like so:

```
Country,City,IP Address External
Australia,Sydney,"101.0.67.53"
Australia,Melbourne,"125.214.65.59"
Belgium,Brussels,"87.238.165.164"
Brazil,São Paulo,"200.170.83.170"
Brazil,Rio de Janeiro,"201.20.20.237"
Canada,Toronto,"208.69.56.166,
208.69.56.171,
208.69.56.172 "
Canada,Montreal,"199.204.45.153,
199.204.45.154,
199.204.45.155,
199.204.45.156"
```

I need to save it as an Allow include file in apache. Like so:

```
Allow from \
72.5.230.111 \
72.5.230.65 \
72.5.230.84
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

webpage="https://www.site24x7.com/multi-location-web-site-monitoring.html"
csv=$(curl -s "$webpage" | grep 'title="CSV"' | \
    sed 's/^.*href="\(http[^ ]*\)".*$/\1/')

echo -e "Allow from \\"
curl -s "$csv" | egrep -o '[0-9.]{7,15}' | paste -s | sed 's/\t/ \\\n/g'
```

Comment: Looks Jedi. I'll test in the AM. Thanks, more than expected.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty and not very robust `sed(1)` one-liner:

```
echo 'Country,City,IP Address External
Australia,Sydney,"101.0.67.53"
Australia,Melbourne,"125.214.65.59"
Belgium,Brussels,"87.238.165.164"
Brazil,São Paulo,"200.170.83.170"
Brazil,Rio de Janeiro,"201.20.20.237"
Canada,Toronto,"208.69.56.166,
208.69.56.171,
208.69.56.172 "
Canada,Montreal,"199.204.45.153,
199.204.45.154,
199.204.45.155,
199.204.45.156"' | 
    sed -e 1d -e 's/"$//' -e 's/^[^"]*"/Allow from /' -e 's/,$/ \\/'
```

Output:

```
Allow from 101.0.67.53
Allow from 125.214.65.59
Allow from 87.238.165.164
Allow from 200.170.83.170
Allow from 201.20.20.237
Allow from 208.69.56.166 \
208.69.56.171 \
208.69.56.172 
Allow from 199.204.45.153 \
199.204.45.154 \
199.204.45.155 \
199.204.45.156
```

Assumptions:

- Every IP address group is surrounded with the double quote (`"`) character
- The `"` character cannot occur anywhere else except to delimit IP groups.
- A comma (`,`) on the end of a line means multiple IP addresses are continued on the next line.

Answer (score 1):

My solution using dns instead:

```
echo -n 'Allow from ';
host -4 -T -t A site24x7.enduserexp.com |
cut -d ' ' -f 4 |
tr '\n' ' '
```